# Parameter learning in augmented Bayesian Networks

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I was reading some material on parameter learning in Bayesian Networks, until this example popped:

[image]

Although I have kind-of understood beta priors, but I am not being able to relate to this question in any way.

Question 1: What does each tuple represent?

The material says, to be consistent, we would want: a11 = a21 + b21 and b11 = b21 + b22

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like: the $a$'s and $b$'s represent the parameters of the beta prior. The first index specifies whether it belongs to $X$ or to $Y$. The second index (only relevant for $Y$) indicates which parameters are used conditional on the state of $X$.